# C++ Variables for wix

Tags: c++, variables, wix

Im currently working with Visual Studio 2010 C++ Custom Action Project

I have a custom action like this:

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall RegProductName(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
char szLocalPath[MAX_PATH];


hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "RegProductName");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

strcpy(szLocalPath, Orc_Get_Product_Name());
MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "ProductName",  szLocalPath);

LExit:
er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

It does not throw up any errors but I'm not sure if i'm doing what I want correctly. 
In this line:

```
strcpy(szLocalPath, Orc_Get_Product_Name());
```

I'm getting the Product name from the function and copying it to szLocalPath. However I want to use this variable many times in other functions and also in my wix project.

Is this the correct way?

```
MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "ProductName",  szLocalPath);
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no issue here but potential **buffer overflow** in `strcpy`. If your function `Orc_Get_Product_Name()` returns path longer than `MAX_PATH`. However, you'd better use `TCHAR` type instead of plain `char` to support Unicode/ANSI builds, and you should really build *with Unicode enabled*.

And I'm sure you want to assign the result of `MsiSetProperty` to `hr` variable.

Additionally, it looks strange that you copy *Product Name* into variable called *Local Path*.
And I can't see where the label `LExit` is used.
The function `ExitOnFailure` does not seem to return control: if `WcaInitialize` was unsuccessful, you should simply return `ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE` or another error code back to MSI engine (rather than terminate the process where your custom action is running).

Comment: Im using Multi-Byte Character Set, Would that be a problem? My variable 'Local Path' was only put in quickly to see if I was doing it correctly, Its now been renamed..:) The only two lines I added was the two Ive taken out in my example the rest was generated by the C++ Custom Action Project. Do you have any examples of what you mean as id be keen to implement it? Also can i use then the Productname variable both in wix project and my DLL project?Thanks

Comment: @NC1 MBCS can be used of course, yet Unicode is better: Windows XP+ support Unicode, and MBCS (or ANSI) versions of functions are implemented as wrappers which convert strings to Unicode, call Unicode API, and convert the result back to MBCS.

Comment: @NC1 I am sorry but I cannot understand what you're talking about in the second part of your comment. You can refer to `ProductName` property in WiX project after it has been set by you Custom Action, if `MsiSetProperty` call was successful. MSI would treat `ProductName` as an empty string or false until it's set.

Comment: Hi, Sorry did not explain that very well at all. My function works perfectly, the thing im trying to do is change the name of the installer to ProductName, however it wont allow me to run my custom action at the very beginning to do this so ProductName ends up being the name of my installer...:(

Comment: So you want to change the name of the installer which is shown in the UI wizard, right? Why can't you set it the desired name during authoring phase rather than runtime? I believe the name displayed in the UI should change as soon as you change the value of the property. Yet the dialogs which have already been created to that point might not update.

Comment: Try to schedule your CA sooner, and check whether `MsiSetProperty` completes successfully. However, I can't understand why you need to change the name at runtime. I'd say it's really weird. MST, or applying a transform `.mst` would be a more natural way of modifying the package. Some installers do apply transformations to .msi package to localize the package to the language selected by user.